# Не могу работать с типом - File, проблемы с компиляцией пакета данного класса

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Объявляю тип File - Нажимаю - alt + enter (для добавления пакета). Но он объявляется не сверху, где он должен быть, а возле слова File. 
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Для тех у кого возникла подобная проблема - 
import java.io.File;

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/file.php

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно выбрать верхний (на рисунке) вариант импорта.

[image: Class java.io File to Import]

А `class Package` не является публичным, поэтому вам высвечивает ошибку при этом варианте импорта.